# The switch just continues

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am doing a simple project just to keep myself a bit fresh. Decided to do a Vending Machine. well I to the end and test it. It does case 1 and 2 just fine but when I get to case 3 it either finishes out the entire program when i select a snack option or if i change it to a if/else in case 3 it will just stop running when i select a snack. Why is it doing this? what can i do to fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Vending 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int choice;
    double deposit = 0;
    double total = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean test = true;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nVending Machine Menu");
        System.out.println("\n \n1. View Items");
        System.out.println("2. Put Money into Machine");
        System.out.println("3. Select an Item");
        System.out.println("4.Recieve Change");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        System.out.println("\nPlease Make a Selection:  ");
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1 :
            System.out.println("\n 1. Fizzy soda : $0.50 \n 2. Gummi Possums : $0.25"
                    + "\n 3. Doggy Bones : $0.25 \n 4. Fruity Punch : $0.50");
            System.out.println("Press ENTER to continue");
            try{System.in.read();}
            catch(Exception e){}
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit: ");
            deposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
            total = total + deposit;
            break;

        case 3:
            Scanner keypad = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("\n 1. Fizzy soda : $0.50 \n 2. Gummi Possums : $0.25"
                    + "\n 3. Doggy Bones : $0.25 \n 4. Fruity Punch : $0.50");
            System.out.println("\nSelect an item: ");
            int snack = keypad.nextInt();
            if (total > 0)
            {
                if(snack == 1)
                {
                    if (total >= .5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Vending Machine dispenses a FIZZY SODA");
                        total = total - .5;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Deposit more money");
                    }

                }
                else if(snack == 2)
                {
                    if (total >= .25)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Vending Machine dispenses a package of GUMMI POSSUMS");
                        total = total - .25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Deposit more money");
                    }
                }
                else if(snack == 3)
                {
                    if(total >= .25)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Vending Machine Dispenses a package of DOGGY BONES");
                        total = total - .25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Deposit more money");
                    }
                }
                else if(snack == 4)
                {
                    if(total >= .5)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Vending Machine Dispenses a can of FRUITY PUNCH");
                        total = total - .5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Deposit more money");
                    }
                }                       
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Please deposit some money");
            }
            keypad.close();

        case 4:
            System.out.println("You recieve " + total + " in change from the Vending Machine");
            total = 0;

        case 5:
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    while (test == true);
    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no need to compare test with true like `while (test == true);` you can directly do `while (test);`

Comment: Thank you. I will clean that right up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `break` at the end of a `case` statement if you do no want to execute the next `case` statement :

```
case 3:
    // do something
    break;   // break to avoid executing case 4
case 4:
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I didnt even see that I was forgetting break.

Answer (score 3):

if you are relying on the break; to get out of cases then you have no break statement in case 3, 4 or 5.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to add `break` keyword at the end your cases, break will prevent executing the next case.

The switch-case should look like this template:

```
case 1:
    // do something
    break;
case 2:
    // do something
    break;   
default:
    // do something
    break;
```

So Add `break` at the end of each case such as:

```
case 4:
        System.out.println("You recieve " + total + " in change from the Vending Machine");
        total = 0;
        break;
```

Read more about [switch-case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) in java.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance: Your `case`s 3 and 4 have no `break` statement at the end.